# Is there a function to send keystrokes in R / RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, keystroke, keystrokes

I'm wondering if there is a function (or some way to create one) in R that can be used to send keystrokes in RStudio.  My anticipated use for this is to check for RStudio updates automatically upon exit by incorporating a send keystroke (ALT+h ALT+u) component into a .Last function I created in the Rprofile.site file.

Or, if anyone knows of another way to automatically check for RStudio updates on exit (or open), I'm all ears.  I already have the .Last function defined such that it checks for R updates automatically upon exit using the updateR() function, but I'd like to also check for RStudio updates at the same time.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does Tools -> Global Options -> General -> [x] Automatically notify me of updates to RStudio do what you need?

Comment: Jonathan:  I would think so, but I have had that box checked, and I wasn't aware of the latest RStudio version (0.98.1103) until I used Help > Check for Updates.  ?!?!